# iOS GCD: DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_BACKGROUND, what does "disk I/O is throttled" mean in document?

Tags: ios, iphone, grand-central-dispatch

As the document says:

> DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_BACKGROUND Items dispatched to the queue will
>   run at background priority, i.e. the queue will be scheduled for
>   execution after all higher priority queues have been scheduled and the
>   system will run items on this queue on a thread with background status
>   as per setpriority(2) (i.e. disk I/O is throttled and the thread’s
>   scheduling priority is set to lowest value).

The last part of the document, what does `"disk I/O is throttled"` mean here?

Does it mean that tasks running at `DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_BACKGROUND` level can't access disk?

Comment: Have you read the reference? [setpriority(2)](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man2/setpriority.2.html) which references [setiopolicy_np(3)](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man3/setiopolicy_np.3.html)?

Comment: @Mats I've read the reference but I still not fully understand.

Answer (score 5):

What we can deduce from the documentation is that `DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_BACKGROUND` is run on a thread with “background status as per [setpriority(2)](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man2/setpriority.2.html)”.

[setpriority(2)](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man2/setpriority.2.html) has a parameter `prio` which can be set to either `0` or `PRIO_DARWIN_BG`. I assume this means that `PRIO_DARWIN_BG` is used and the documentation describes this as:

> When a thread or process is in a background state the scheduling priority is set to the lowest value, disk IO is throttled (with behavior similar to using [setiopolicy_np(3)](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man3/setiopolicy_np.3.html) to set a throttleable policy), and network IO is throttled for any sockets opened after going into background state.  Any previously opened sockets are not affected.

[setiopolicy_np(3)](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man3/setiopolicy_np.3.html) can set the thread I/O policy to `IOPOL_IMPORTANT`, `IOPOL_STANDARD`, `IOPOL_UTILITY`, `IOPOL_THROTTLE`, or `IOPOL_PASSIVE`. It describes the effect of throttled disk I/O as:

> If a throttleable request occurs within a small time window of a request of higher priority, the thread that issued the throttleable I/O is forced to a sleep for a short period.  (Both this
>        window and the sleep period are dependent on the policy of the throttleable I/O.)  This slows down the
>        thread that issues the throttleable I/O so that higher-priority I/Os can complete with low-latency and
>        receive a greater share of the disk bandwidth.  Furthermore, an IMPORTANT I/O request may bypass a previously
>        issued throttleable I/O request in kernel or driver queues and be sent to the device first.  In
>        some circumstances, very large throttleable I/O requests will be broken into smaller requests which are
>        then issued serially.

Which basically means that reading and writing to disk may be slowed or delayed, if another thread with higher priority is also accessing the disk. So no, it does not prevent tasks running at `DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_BACKGROUND` from accessing the disk.

Answer (score 0):

throttling means it controls the rate of I/O based on available resources. On low memery condition it many reduce the number of I/O process, and slows down.